# Database to a Network drive

Tags: backup, sql-server

What would be the syntax to backup MS SQL Database 2005 to a network drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map the network share to a drive letter.

Try one of [these options](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124707/backup-and-restore-through-mapped-network-drive):

> 1. Directly type the UNC path of the server where you would like to backup
>      /restore from [Eg: type
>      `\\servername\Sharename\Filename.bak`
>      in the 'Locate database files'
>      dialog's 'File name' text box]
> 2. Create a backup device pointing to the UNC path. Then backup to this
>      device.

--

EDIT:

I tried both methods and they work. Make sure your `MSSQLSERVER` service is running under an account with permissions to write to the network path you're trying to get to.

Comment: Backup Database Prod_10 to disk = '\\backup\Prod_10.bak'   i tried this an is nor working getting error operating system error 3 ( the system can find the path ) I have map a drive on the server

Comment: I said you can't do it with a mapped drive. Did you even try the suggestions in my answer?

Comment: i tried that. my servername is backup have a folder call ProdBack Here is the syntax i used   Backup database Prod_10 to disk = '\\backup\ProdBack\Prod_10.bak'

Comment: See my updated answer. Check your SQL Service is running under the correct permissions to write to the network share.

Comment: Yes please. I think it was permission issues.

Comment: It is permission issues I just check it again. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad I could help.